# SQL Permissions to Add data and how to verify?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, database-permissions

I'm looking for a good way to maintain permissions on who can add data to a database in a C# app and SQL Server 2005.

I need to explain though to make this clear. So let's take an example of this:

I have two users `Bob` and `Jim`, both have been added to the SQL permissions so they have write access to the database. Now all access is based on Domain User Accounts. All other users only have read access.

Now I have a couple tables such as:

- Users
- UserPermissions
- Books
- BookPublishers

So `UserPermissions` contains a list of Users and BookPublishers. So for example: `Bob` has permission to add books for `MS Press` and `Jim` has permission to add books for `O'Reilly`.

Now I need to verify this information and limit what they can add.

So say `Jim` uses my application from a command line and he writes something like:

> `Addbook.exe "C# 3.0 in a Nutshell" "O'Reilly"`

The tool should go ahead and add the book to the book table.

Now say `Bob` tries the same command, the tool should error as he does not have permission to add books by `O'Reilly`.

Right now I need to know how to do a couple things.

- Verify that a user first has write permission to the SQL Server
- Verify that the user has write permission to add `books` by a specific publisher
- Also I need to verify that the above is true before the tool actually tries to add the data, i.e. I need verification feedback first before the tool continues

Now I'm not 100% worried about the user from injecting malicious data, though it would be nice to stop that, but it's an internal tool and I guess I can trust the users... (possibly)

Either way I don't know where to be begin, my SQL skills are very much lacking.

Akk, one last thing, I don't want to add data using store procedures.

Comment: You'll need to query the SQL Server permissions metadata directly. There are some stored procedures you can call that will do this, but I seem to remember it's not a trivial task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, let's break this down:

Verify that a user can write to the table (this will return 1 if true, 0 if not):

```
SELECT isnull(has_perms_by_name('MyDb.dbo.MyTable', 'OBJECT', 'INSERT'), 0)
```

Verify that a user can write that publisher:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM UserPermissions WHERE
UserName = 'username' AND Publisher = 'publisher'
```

Now, that's the SQL for those, and not the actual C#. To get the values in C#:

```
SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection("connection_string_goes_here");
SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

SqlConn.Open();
SqlCmd.Connection = SqlConn;
SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT isnull(has_perms_by_name('MyDb.dbo.MyTable', " +
    "'OBJECT', 'INSERT'), 0)"

if (SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar())
{
   SqlCmd.CommandText =
       "SELECT count(*) FROM UserPermissions WHERE " +
       "Username = " + System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\" + 
           System.Environment.UserName + " " +
       AND Publisher = @Publisher";
   SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Publisher", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
   SqlCmd.Parameters("@Publisher").Value = PublisherInput;

   if(SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar())
   {
       SqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
       SqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Books (Title, Publisher) VALUES " +
                            "(@Title, @Publisher)";
       SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
       SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Publisher", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
       SqlCmd.Parameters("@Title").Value = TitleInput;
       SqlCmd.Parameters("@Publisher").Value = PublisherInput;
       SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}

SqlCmd.Dispose();
SqlConn.Close();
SqlConn.Dispose();
```

As a final note, **cleanse your input**. Use parameters in your application, and **do not trust any user, even internal ones**. I can't stress that enough.

Edit: Because there are more than one way to skin a cat, I felt it foolish of me to not include the LINQ to SQL solution (at least to the count issue):

```
int PermsAvailable = (from up in db.UserPermissions
                      where up.Username == 
                          System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\" + 
                          System.Environment.UserName
                      && up.Publisher == PublisherInput
                      select up).Count();
if(PermsAvailable)
{
    var NewBook = New Book with {.Title = TitleInput, .Publisher = PublisherInput};
    db.Books.Add(NewBook);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, while I'm not so bad with the code, it was more if the idea of checking permissions and then continuing is the right way to go. Looks like it's not bad and this pretty much covers what I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=481) has an explanation of various methods of securing applications with specific permissions.  It's worth reading the rest of the series and also the prior ASP.NET 2.0 series in order to understand the architecture being used.

Comment: A good article about how to add a SQL Server ASP.NET membership provider to a site - but it uses code to verify role membership before permission is granted to do a task. The situation in the question is question is where SQL Server security itself is used to grant or deny permission to the database - and the C# code needs to determine what these permissions are.

Comment: This is pretty useful as I need some asp.net control also. The only catch is that for this question it was slightly off topic.

Answer (score 1):

From a usability point of view, I wonder if it wouldn't be friendlier to manage editability in the UI. As a user, if I enter data and get slapped with a message that I don't have permission to make that entry, I am not going to be encouraged to continue participating in your website.

If a user is not able to add any entries to the database, you could display a read-only page (or DIV). Users with permissions to save new entries would get an editable page/DIV.

For a user who is permitted to save some categories of information, but not others, would it work to limit the entries in that category by using a drop-down list? For example, Bob's publisher drop-down list displays MSPress, and Jim's list includes O'Reilly. That way, they can see clearly from those lists what they are permitted to do before they attempt to add the data. Permissions aren't a secret, hidden from the user.

Comment: This will actually be used for both API, CMD and GUI tool. So for most part it is going to be ok.
The CMD tool though is designed to pass any parameter as needed and the user needs to verify this. It is expected they get this right and if not the tool will error.