# Query to get roles and permissions granted to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

I executed the following script to create mydb_user and mydb_admin with limited permissions.

STEP1: Ran these scripts on azure masterdb

```
CREATE LOGIN mydb_admin 
WITH PASSWORD = 'nnn' 
GO
CREATE LOGIN mydb_user 
WITH PASSWORD = 'nnnnnnnnn' 
GO
```

Step2: Ran the below scripts on the actual azure db  eg., mydb

```
CREATE USER mydb_admin  FROM LOGIN mydb_admin ;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'mydb_admin';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'mydb_admin';
GRANT CONNECT TO mydb_admin;
GRANT SELECT TO mydb_admin;
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[procDumpRowsInto_De_Common] TO [mydb_admin] AS [dbo]

CREATE USER mydb_user FROM LOGIN mydb_user;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'mydb_user';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'mydb_user';
GRANT CONNECT TO mydb_user;
GRANT SELECT TO mydb_user;
```

Now I want to see if the roles and permissions are set correctly. Is there a query that I can run to see this? For instance, I want to see the effective roles and permissions for dbusers mydb_user,mydb_admin on my database myDb?

Comment: Same as on SQL Server, you can call sys.fn_my_permissions. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12789102

Comment: Invalid object name 'fn_my_permissions'.  I tried that already, but I am not able to find any such object  'fn_my_permissions' in my azure 'master' db

Comment: You are right, fn_my_permissions is not there on Azure SQL DB. You can call 
select HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME (db_name(), 'DATABASE', 'SELECT') to check whether a specific permission is granted or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, fn_my_permissions is not there on Azure SQL DB. You can call select HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME (db_name(), 'DATABASE', 'SELECT'), or other permission you want to check for, to check whether a specific permission is granted or not either directly or via a role.